# How to use electron-packager to create a custom icon in Linux?

Tags: javascript, electron

Following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz5SnmBzBXc

I did this: `electron-packager . MyApp --platform=linux --arch=x64 --version=0.37.2 && cp icon.png MyApp-linux-x64/resources/atom.png`

The icon is saved into the resources folder, but the icon doesn't show in my Ubuntu left panel (I just see the default cog).

What the correct way of setting up the icon for Linux?

**EDIT:**

I also tried this: `var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    icon: 'file://' + __dirname + '/resources/atom.png',`

No luck.

**EDIT 2**

Here's a screenshot of the whole thing:

[image]

Comment: Offtopic: i love the LINE icon. It means that I'm not alone in the WhatsApp fight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command: `electron-packager . MyApp --platform=linux --arch=x64 --version=0.37.2 --icon=<path/to/your-icon-name>`