# How to package custom icon in Electron for OSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm, electron

How do you add custom application icons to Electron apps for `OSX`? I have packaged the app using electron packager with the `asar flag` and can view the package contents to see the `atom.icns` icon file - though replacing it with my `.icns` file does not update the main application icon.

There is a linux focussed question here though it doesn't provide much `OSX` info: [How to use electron-packager to create a custom icon in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041127/how-to-use-electron-packager-to-create-a-custom-icon-in-linux)

Here is my package command:

```
electron-packager . HttpWizard --platform=all --arch=all --version=0.36.0 --asar=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the icon option:

```
--icon=/path/to/icon.icns
```

***icon***

> the icon file to use as the icon for the app. Note: Format
>   depends on platform.

↳ [electron-packager usage.txt](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/9849daef5356ea810ab4e509c1061d81b2ea80a0/usage.txt#L34)

Comment: Thanks I'L'I - I re-packaged and this worked perfectly on OSX 10.11.2.

Comment: @user6144056: You're welcome! If this solved your issue, be sure to click the checkmark on the left.

Comment: Done I actually wasn't sure how to mark as solved, had to find the answer on stackoverflow..